# Enable taking screenshot of a App after disabled using FLAG_SECURE

Tags: android, android-screen-support, android-security

Using the code below I prevent users taking screenshots of my app. I want to implement "enable screenshot button". Is it possible? Which concept should I use?

```
 public class FlagSecureTestActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

          getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,
                     LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
          setContentView(R.layout.main);
  }
 }
```

Comment: Readability and Spelling correction

Comment: I wish all app developers would think of a button to disable their additional flag.

Answer (score 0):

You could restart the activity and this time not set the SECURE flag.

In my app, I have a switch in settings to enable or disable the secure flag. Then I simply do not set it if the settings specifies that I am allowed to take screenshots.